# How do I fix a java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: error for a simple hello world?

Tags: java

I'm new to Java coding, and I'm confused. I am using VS Code with the Java extension pack on a MacBook (not sure if this is relevant information or not). I wrote this:

```
package ICS111;

public class hello {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            System.out.println("bruh moment");
        }
    }
```

To compile/execute, I used the command javac hello.java, which created a class called hello .class in the ICS111 folder. If I ls in my ICS11 folder, it outputs:
**(base) Kylies-MBP-3:ICS111 kylie$ ls
hello.class     hello.java**

After this, I tried using java hello, but it gives me this error: 
**Error: Could not find or load main class hello
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: ICS111/hello (wrong name: hello)**

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18093929/11979793



this should answer your question

Comment: Your class and filename should be same (case-sensitive), if they are not java will complain that way.

Comment: Navigate to your src folder using terminal. The first command should be to compile the java file. You can do this by typing the following `javac hello.java`. Then type the following to run `java hello`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I compile and run a program in Java on my Mac?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2360995/how-do-i-compile-and-run-a-program-in-java-on-my-mac)

Comment: Your code is in a package. `cd..` then `java ICS111.hello` - the package name is part of the class.

Comment: Thanks for all the links! I was in the wrong directory and I did not know I had to go one directory back. Thanks for the help!